# How to pass variable from template to other elements in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am really new into php, and cakephp3.
I created template which is used by almost every email, only text in emails is something what is changing, so i get text by `$this->fetch('email.text')`, and in email i am passing it by `$this->append('email.text')`.

I want to declare `$variable = "some string"` and pass it from template to email. How i can archive that?

Comment: What do you mean by template ? Did you create an element ?

Comment: yeah my bad, i am extending emails by $this->extend('template') and i want to user variable from that element

Comment: then you can pass an array along with it and access it as per below mentioned solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created an element then you can call that element and pass the variable like below:

```
echo $this->element('email.text', array('var1' => 'some string'));
```

and inside the element file you can access the variable as `$var1`.

Hope this helps.